# Is there a way I can flip objects like a mirror?

Tags: fabricjs

I have two canvas and when I draw something on the first one, I want to be able to draw the exact same thing but flipped like a mirror in the second one. Is there a way to do this?

I tried using flipX, but it doesnt work the way I want.

Comment: Either of: 1) group everything and flip 2) rotate canvas itself with CSS transform

Comment: How do I flip everything? With flipX?

Comment: If i rotate canvas with CSS the scaling/rotation/mouse movement is not accurate after rotation